# How to run a string from an input file as python code?

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating something along the likes of a text adventure game. I have a .yaml file that is my input. This file looks something like this

```
node_type: 
  action
title: 
  Do some stuff
info: 
  This does some stuff and things
script:
  'print("hello world")
  print(ret_val)
  foo.bar(True)
  ret_val = (foo.bar() == True)
  if (thing):
      print(thing)
  print(ret_val)
  '
```

**My end goal is to have my python program run the script portion of the yaml file exactly as if it had been copy pasted into the main code.** (I know there are about ten bazillion security reasons I should not be running user input like this, but I am the only one writing these nodes, and the only one using this program so I'm mostly just ignoring this fact...)

Currently my attempt goes like this: I load my yaml file as a dict using pyyaml

```
node = yaml.safe_load(file.yaml)
```

Then I'm trying to use exec to run my code and hitting a lot of problems, I can't run `if` statements, I simply get a syntax error, and I can't get any sort of return value from my code. I've tried this as a work around:

```
def main()
    ret_val = "test";
    thing = exec(node['script'], globals(),locals())
    print(ret_val)
```

which when run with the above .yaml file prints

```
>> hello world
>> test
>> True
>> test
```

for some reason not actually modifying any of my main variables even though I fed them to exec.

Is there any way for me to work around these issues or is there an all together better way to be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this would be to parse the code out and save it to a `.py` file, from which it can be imported dynamically, for example by [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html).

You might want to encapsulate parsed code into a function, which you can then easily call to invoke your action. Also, it would make sense to specify some default imports there.